# Crystal module path require issue

Tags: crystal-lang

This is my first post so please excuse the brevity. I'm learning crystal and trying to include a file which has a shared name with another file in another path. According to the [documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/requiring_files.html) I can use `require "path/to/modules/"` and include all files within, but when I do this I and then use the imported class, it tells me the class does not exist...

Nothing in the documentation seems to work. Is there some addon module I need to get the paths to work properly or am I misunderstanding something or do I have some syntax error?

This is my code (Using the example on the home page)

```
require "http/server"
require "modules/HttpRequest"

server = HTTP::Server.new do |context|
  context.response.print(request.result)
end

server.listen(80)
```

And the file `HttpRequest.cr` is in `/modules/`.

The error I get

```
Error in Server.cr:2: while requiring "modules/HttpRequest": can't find file 'modules/HttpRequest'

If you're trying to require a shard:
- Did you remember to run `shards install`?
- Did you make sure you're running the compiler in the same directory as your shard.yml?

require "modules/HttpRequest"
^
```

Comment: Surely the `/` dashes are pointing to root and not relative to the working directory? In which case the first require should be failing as well which is a little strange that it's not...

Comment: No sorry I have made an error in writing my question - the slashes are not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `require "modules/HttpRequest"` will look up `modules/HttpRequest` in `CRYSTAL_PATH` according to the [require rules](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/requiring_files.html).

To require a file relative to the current file you need to use `require "./modules/HttpRequest"`.